# Problems with through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looking to loop through an association and include a through association as well. I'm getting an **undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass** error on the below.

I have an account model which has_many sales, which works fine. But `sales` is linked via `previousAgents` through `previous_agent_id` and this is where i'm having the problem.

**Account Model**

```
has_many :sales, primary_key: 'account_id'
```

**Sales Model**

```
belongs_to :previousAgent, primary_key: 'previous_agent_id'
```

**Account View**

```
<% @account.sales.each do |p| %>
 <p>Previous Agent <%= p.previousAgent.name %></p>
 <p>Date: <%= p.date.strftime("%d %B, %Y") %></p>
 <p>Comments: <%= p.comment %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can previousAgents be nil in any case? If so you should check for p.previousAgent.nil? before printing the name.

Comment: I have placed conditionals in there to check for that, and it displays nothing when there is data there.

Comment: BTW it is usually good to stick to Rails naming conventions - in this case, you should name your association `previous_agents`.

Comment: Check my edited answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked out a solution for this. I'm unsure as why this has worked though.

I added a foreign_key to my **Sales Model**.

```
belongs_to :previousAgent, primary_key: 'previous_agent_id', foreign_key: 'previous_agent_id'
```

If anyone can shed some light on why both primary and foreign key is needed that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<%= p.previousAgents.first.name %>
```

Account has_many previousAgents

So, `p.previousAgents` will return Array of the `previousAgent` if you want to show all the previous agents do following.

```
<% @account.sales.each do |p| %>
 <% for agent in p.previousAgents %>
   <p>Previous Agent <%= agent.name %></p>
 <% end %>
 <p>Date: <%= p.date.strftime("%d %B, %Y") %></p>
 <p>Comments: <%= p.comment %></p>
<% end %>
```

EDITED, as Question is get edited.

```
<%= p.previousAgent.try(:name) %>
```

So, if `p.previousAgent` is `nil` it will not throw an error & if `p.previousAgent` returns the object of `PreviousAgent` then above code will return the values of the `name` attribute.

Check [`try`](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/Object/try) method here

Comment: Thanks Salil. It works in the sense that the page loads, but no data loads, and my database has data.

Comment: <%= p.previousAgent %> should at least return something, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Since each sale can have only 1 sales agent define your associations as follows,

```
Sale.rb

belongs_to :PreviousAgent, foreign_key: previous_agent_id

Agent.rb

has_many :sales
```

Then, in your code since, you are looping through each and every sale that belongs to an account,

```
<% @account.sales.each do |p| %>
 <p>Previous Agent <%= p.previousAgent.name %></p>
 <p>Date: <%= p.date.strftime("%d %B, %Y") %></p>
 <p>Comments: <%= p.comment %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the path i'm heading down now. But still getting the undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass error.